# communicate between ActionResult and worker thread

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading

I have an action (StartJob) that starts a long running worker thread. I'm trying to have another action (GetStatusFromWrokerThread) return the current status of the LongRunningJob process. Is that possible to do?

```
    public ActionResult StartJob(int[] instList)
    {
        permissionCheck = new Thread(LongRunningJob);
        permissionCheck.Start();

        var jr = new JsonNetResult();
        jr.Formatting = Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.Indented;
        jr.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore;
        jr.Data = (inQueue <= 0?0:inQueue);

        return jr;
    }


    public ActionResult GetStatusFromWrokerThread()
    {
        // how to get a status code or message from LongRunningJob 
        // the thread started in the action above


        var jr = new JsonNetResult();
        jr.Formatting = Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.Indented;
        jr.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore;
        jr.Data = (inQueue <= 0 ? 0 : inQueue);

        return jr;
    }
```

Comment: Where is the status code or message you want to access defined?

Comment: See BackgroundWorker ProgressChanged event  example on following webpage : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: The message is defined in an .cshtml page.